# Android application cant write to file at second time

Tags: android, android-emulator, file-writing

***I have problem with writing data to file in Android Emulator***. In my Android Emulator in ***/data*** folder I have created ***MyLogs*** folder and give full access to it. After I run my application and it create ***Log.txt*** file and place it in ***/data/MyLogs*** folder. All is Okay. After I have run my application in second time and application try to write some information in same file, but it cant't.

I think the main reason is that then at first time my application creates file the creator is different from second time. thats why I can't write to file second time !

Who have any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it can't" write to the file?  Errors?

Comment: I create File from native code ... ans so when I want to write in it in second time I can't (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a file writable for more than once use `Context.MODE_APPEND`

### Sample Code

```
FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = openFileOutput("nuzz.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);
                fos.write(string.getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {

                fos = openFileOutput("nuzz.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);

                fos.write("bye".getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Thanks
Deepak